# What is The choice

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophets, death, funeral

When angel of death descended to remove soul of last prophet. He said he was given the choice like all prophets what is the the choice?

> No soul of a Prophet is taken until he has been shown his place in Paradise and ***then he is given the choice*** (bukhari [4463](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4463))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite apparent if you read the whole hadith. However it is also more explicitly narrated in other ahadith. The choice is between continuing to live longer in this world or transitioning to the afterlife right then.

> لا يموت نبي حتى يخير بين الدنيا والآخرة
>
> No Prophet dies till he is given the option to select either the worldly life or the life of the Hereafter
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4435)</sup>